# How to retrieve all columns row count in a large table with millions of records

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014

How to retrieve all columns row count in a large table with millions of records?

Example:

```
SELECT * FROM playernames;

 id |       name       
----+------------------
 38 | Abe Lincoln
 39 | NULL
 40 | Ronald Reagan
(3 rows)
```

I want to know the count of each column in one query

```
SELECT COUNT(ID), COUNT(NAME)
FROM PLAYERNAMEs;
```

result:

```
3 2
```

But as table has 10 millions of records its taking a lot of time and some times i am not getting columns count.

Is there any quicker way to retrieve this count. Thanks

Comment: I don't believe there is any faster method.

Comment: You'll get better performance  with a clustered columnstore index on the table but that's a significant change and is only available in Enterprise Edition in the SQL 2014 world.